# Does creating singleton inside application class cause memory leak?

Tags: android, kotlin, singleton, android-context

I have an `Authenticator` class which needs a `context` for doing some task with `SharedPreferences`. I created a singleton of the class inside my custom application class so that I don't need to pass the context everytime to create an instance of my `Authenticator`. Is this a correct approach or it can cause memory leak or other issue?

My `Application` class :

```kotlin
class App : Application() {

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        //Plant Timber for Logging in Debug Build
        if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
            Timber.plant(Timber.DebugTree())
        }

        Authenticator.createInstance(this)

    }

    ...
    ....
}
```

On other classes I can access the singleton like this :

```kotlin
Authenticator.INSTANCE
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When objects like `Context`,`Activity`,`Application`, ... that have lifecycles are stored as static or in static objects you should take care of clearing them as their lifecycle ends. If you do so, there should not be any problem with storing them. Just release the instances when the 
lifecycle ends.

For more clarification, `Activity's` lifecycle ends with `onDestroy` and you should override this function and release accesses to it properly. for further details you can visit android documentation for Lifecycles.
For cases like app termination, all the memory used by app will be cleaned and leak won't occur thus you shouldn't get worried about accesses in `Application` class like saving global app context.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.But when does the lifecycle of application class ends?

Comment: And as I am using Kotlin. I am using companion objects not static methods.

Comment: about your first question I edited my answer. for the second comment, the main concept behind them are similar and the references should get tracked so they wouldn't be accessible as they are destroyed.